# Definition of exterior derivative from a connection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I fail to see what is the meaning of the symbol $d_{\nabla}$ in (1.2) of

http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9712042v2.pdf

I know the meaning of that symbol in the context of forms taking values on some vector bundle with connection $\nabla$, but this is different since it is a boundary operator of the standard de Rham complex which at degree zero acts as $\nabla$.

Thanks.

Comment: In section 1.3 of the same article the author writes $d_{\nabla} = \nabla$. Here the symbol is meant to emphasize that the author not only considers this (flat) connection but its (unique) extension to the whole deRham complex.

Comment: @DBS: I thought he meant that $d_{\nabla} =\nabla$ only acting on functions. What is this extension of $\nabla$ to the whole deRham complex? How acting on a $k$-form with $\nabla$ you obtain a $(k+1)$-form? (different from what you would have obtained by acting with the deRham exterior derivative).

Comment: It is pointed out in the answer below. Let $C^{k} = \Omega^{k} \otimes M.$ The point is if we want to define a derivative $\tilde{d}: C^{k} \rightarrow C^{k+1}$ would be $\tilde{d}(\omega \otimes s) = d(\omega)\otimes s - \omega \wedge (\nabla s)$ (here $d$ is usual exterior derivative). You can check that $\tilde{d}^{2} = 0$ (using $\nabla^{2} = 0$ i.e. flat connection). This agrees with the usual definition of a connection at $C^{0}$. One can show by induction that the extension is unique of one requires that the extension is a derivation in each variable.

Comment: @DBS: Thanks. I guess you meant $C^{k} = \Omega^{k}\otimes TM$? If that is the case then I understand: you are considering $k$-forms taking values in $TM$ and applying the standard exterior covariant derivative for forms taking values in a vector bundle with a connection.

Comment: Yes you are right, in your notation (and that of the paper) you are using $M$ for the manifold and $TM$ for the tangent bundle. The formalism I mentioned works for any vector bundle and more generally any coherent sheaf over a manifold. I apologize for my incoherence but essentially I was using $M$ to denote any coherent sheaf and didn't mention the underlying manifold at all. So to summarize: My $M$ is your $TM$  and the tensor in my notation is over the sheaf of functions on the manifold $M$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you know about connections on the tangent bundle.
These connections induce connections on the tensor bundle $\mathcal{T}^{r,s}M$ of $(r,s)$ tensor fields.
Given $∇ : Γ(TM) \to Γ(TM \otimes T^{*}M)$ there is a unique connection $d_∇ : Γ(\mathcal{T}^{r,s}M) \to Γ(\mathcal{T}^{r,s}M \otimes T^{*}M)$ satisfying

- $d_∇ = ∇$ on $TM$,
- $(d_∇X)f = X(f)$ for functions $f ∈ C^{∞}(M)$,
- Product rule: $(d_∇X)(F \otimes G) = d_∇X F \otimes G + F \otimes d_∇X G$,
- Trace invariance: $d_∇X(\mathrm{tr}(F)) = \mathrm{tr}(d_∇X F)$.

The almost complex structure $J ∈ Γ(TM \otimes T^{*}M)$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor.
Similarly, this works for forms.

Comment: isn't that just the natural extension of $\nabla$ to act on arbitrary tensors? Is there a need to use a different symbol than $\nabla$ for that?